# How can I update android demo app on expo?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am a new expo and react-native user.

I am building mny react-native app with expo SDK36 and there is **a QR code** for my app on my dashboard on `https://expo.io/@myusername/myproject`.

Scanning the QR code with my Android phone will open the demo app with the expo client. **Unfortunately, it is an old build**

I want to **publish the change** so the demo app is **the latest**.

I have tried to run locally:

- `expo build:web`: build the `web-build`
- `expo build:android`: build a signed `apk`
- `expo build:ios -t simulator`: build a `tar.gz`

None of these build commands seems to publish the online demo app. I haven't found a publish command.

How can I update the online expo demo android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: When using an answer to suggest something to try, please add why you think it will solve the problem, what risks it has, and also how to undo it if it doesn't solve the problem.